# CKEditor - dropdown not working in IE

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor Version 4.5 and the issue is only with IE (using v.11).

The CKEditor is implemented in a JSF Dialog (Richfaces), and everytime I click a drop down it shows for about 0.5 sec and then it disappears. The console dosen't show any errors.

First I thought mabye the dialog loses it's focus but I've allready tried to set the focus after click on the editor back to the dialog, but that did not resolve the problem. Any suggests what the problem could be?

**EDIT**

```
<div class="editor-container">
    <rich:editor  id="editor" value="#{bean.editor}">
        <f:facet name="config">
             toolbar: 'custom',
             startupFocus: true,
             toolbar_custom:
             [
             { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
             '/',
             { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
             { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
             { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] },
             { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize' ] }
            ]
        </f:facet>  
    </rich:editor> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample where we could reproduce your problem?

Comment: @NielsNet that is my implementation

Comment: 1. You could try using  `config.baseFloatZIndex = 102000;`
2. I don't know which RichFaces version you use but if your uses jQuery then you might want to look at the whole issue here https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9087#comment:39 with a solution in comments 30 and 39 (depending on version jQuery used).

Answer (score 0):

Only happens inside twitter-bootstrap modal.
Solution: If the font, size dropdowns are not working in IE, please copy the code below.

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() 
{
    modal_this = this
    $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) 
    {
      if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length
         && $(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_contents cke_reset')) 
         {
            modal_this.$element.focus()
         }
    })
};
```